# Getting cell id through adb

Tags: java, android, adb

Is it possible to get a list of the available cells(with it's ID, MCC/MNC and power level of each signal) through adb (Rooted phone)? Is there a specific adb command that would list all of this? I know it's possible through android using the telephony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is adb logcat and filter using grep.

```
adb logcat | grep -E 'MCC|MNC'
```

will give you info about MCC and MNC

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I decided to go on a tangent and do it behind the scenes; meaning, through adb but not directly. I wrote another android program just to find all this info, saves it to a file in sdcard and I just read it off that. So i just run the apk through adb, does it's thing in the background and I just read the file

Comment: MCC and MNC in no way convey the information about a cell ID. What kind of log message are you pointing your grep at?